# I have three dropdown and I want that when I select the value of first dropdown, that value should not appear in second dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

```
<select class="js-example-templating" name="mem1">
            <?php
              $query = "select * from user";
              $query_result = query($query);
            while($row = fetch_array($query_result)) {
                echo "<option value='{$row['user_id']}'>{$row['user_id']} - {$row['name']}</option>";
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <select class="js-example-templating" name="mem2">
            <?php
              $query = "select * from user";
              $query_result = query($query);
            while($row = fetch_array($query_result)) {
                echo "<option value='{$row['user_id']}'>{$row['user_id']} - {$row['name']}</option>";
            }
            ?>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <select class="js-example-templating" name="mem3">
            <?php
              $query = "select * from user";
              $query_result = query($query);
            while($row = fetch_array($query_result)) {
                echo "<option value='{$row['user_id']}'>{$row['user_id']} - {$row['name']}</option>";
            }
            ?>
          </select>

function formatState (state) {
  if (!state.id) {
    return state.text;
  }
    var $state = $(
    '<span>' + state.text + '</span>'
  );
  return $state;
};
$(".js-example-templating").select2({
  templateResult: formatState
});
</script>
```

I have 3 dropdowns and I want that when I select the value in 1st dropdown, that value will not appear in 2nd and 3rd dropdown and when I select that value of second dropdown, then that value will not come in 3rd dropdown. I am using Select2 library for live search in dropdown and due to that select2 library, AJAX call is not working otherwise it will be super easy. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you must use javascript array data source and update those arrays for the 2nd and 3rd dropdown.

Comment: Or you can add some javascript and on change of any dropdown just hide the selected option in following dropdowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the data for all the three select2 dropdowns. Right now you are giving the same data for all three dropdowns. You can do try two approaches here:

1.Create an array with initial values. When some value is selected by 1st dropdown, copy the array values except the selected one to a different array. Now use this array for the second dropdown. You can use onchange event on the dropdowns to detect change and updating the array for next dropdown.

```
<select class="js-example-templating1" name="mem1" onchange="updateNextArray()">
        <?php
          $query = "select * from user";
          $query_result = query($query);
        while($row = fetch_array($query_result)) {
            echo "<option value='{$row['user_id']}'>{$row['user_id']} - {$row['name']}</option>";
        }
        ?>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <select class="js-example-templating2" name="mem2" onchange="updateNextArray()">
        <?php
          $query = "select * from user";
          $query_result = query($query);
        while($row = fetch_array($query_result)) {
            echo "<option value='{$row['user_id']}'>{$row['user_id']} - {$row['name']}</option>";
        }
        ?>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <select class="js-example-templating3" name="mem3" onchange="updateNextArray()">
        <?php
          $query = "select * from user";
          $query_result = query($query);
        while($row = fetch_array($query_result)) {
            echo "<option value='{$row['user_id']}'>{$row['user_id']} - {$row['name']}</option>";
        }
        ?>
      </select>
<script>
function updateNextArray(){
//update array here
}
function formatState (state) {
if (!state.id) {
return state.text;
}
var $state = $(
'<span>' + state.text + '</span>'
);
return $state;
};
$(".js-example-templating1").select2({
data: Array1,
templateResult: formatState
});
$(".js-example-templating2").select2({
data: Array2,
templateResult: formatState
});
$(".js-example-templating3").select2({
data: Array3,
templateResult: formatState
});
</script>
```

2.AJAX will work if you use it properly.

```
$(".js-example-templating").select2({
    ajax: {
        url: '../../subjects.json', // or api endpoint which supplies the array
        dataType: 'json',
    });
```

Comment: How to dynamically assign Array to select2 data?

Comment: use onchange event on the first dropdown. Filter the array. Initialize the second dropdown with the filtered array.